# Materialize-css javascript functions not found in Aurelia project

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, materialize

I've created a custom attribute to control the lifecycle of a materilaize `select` element:

```
import {customAttribute} from 'aurelia-templating';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

@customAttribute('material-select')
@inject(Element)
export class MaterialSelect {
    element: Element = null;

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        console.log("ATTACHED");
        console.log(`The attached element is: ${this.element}`);
        $(this.element).material_select();
    }

    detached() {
        console.log("DETACHED");
        $(this.element).material_select('destroy');
    }
}
```

Additionally, I've installed materialize-css with:

```
jspm install npm:materialize-css
```

... and I've imported materilialize in `main.ts` with:

```
import materialize from 'materialize-css';
```

But, whenever an element with the `material-select` attribute tries to load I get this console output:

```
ATTACHED
The attached element is: [object HTMLSelectElement]
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a function
```

How do I get the materialize-css javascript functions to be recognized from within Aurelia?

Comment: The materialize js components (especially the select) are tricky to integrate with data-binding.  There are examples [here](http://jdanyow.github.io/aurelia-breeze-northwind).  They could use some refactoring but should give you some ideas.

Comment: The Northwind Github [repo](https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze-northwind) looks very similar to what I've done: materialize is a jspm dependency, imported in `main.js`, and then used. I only see 2 differences: Northwind uses an older version of materilize, and Northwind is not a Typescript project. Though I can't see why those diffences would cause a problem.

Comment: I've written a blog about integrating third party libraries into aurelia that might interest you. See: http://davismj.me/blog/aurelia-drag-and-drop/

Comment: I've written a blog about creating custom elements for wrapping css frameworks here: http://davismj.me/blog/semantic-custom-element/

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the npm version of the package and install the github version instead:

```shell
jspm uninstall npm:materialize-css
jspm install github:Dogfalo/materialize
```

By installing the github version the [package override](https://github.com/jspm/registry/blob/master/package-overrides/github/Dogfalo/materialize%400.97.0.json) will be used and the package will be installed with the correct dependencies (jquery + css).

Then you'll be able to do this:

```
import $ from 'Dogfalo/materialize';

$('.foo').material_select();
```

*Note: the steps above will not work until [this PR](https://github.com/jspm/registry/pull/650) is merged*

Comment: Running `jspm install github:Dogfalo/materialize` pulls empty directories. The only file within `jspm_packages/github/Dogfalo` is `.jspm-hash`. The rest is empty folders. Is that how it's supposed to be?

Comment: looks like the package override is wrong.  I created a PR for the jspm registry.  Will update my answer when it gets accepted.  Shouldn't take long